# How to bypass cloudflare bot/ddos protection in Scrapy?

Tags: javascript, python, cookies, scrapy

I used to scrape e-commerce webpage occasionally to get product prices information. I have not used the scraper built using *Scrapy* in a while and yesterday was trying to use it - I run into a problem with bot protection.

It is using CloudFlare’s DDOS protection which is basically using JavaScript evaluation to filter out the browsers (and therefore scrapers) with JS disabled. Once the function is evaluated, the response with calculated number is generated. In return, service sends back two authentication cookies which attached to each request allow to normally crawl the site. [Here](https://khromov.wordpress.com/2013/02/05/cloudflare-client-side-ddos-detection-how-does-it-work/)'s the description of how it works.

I have also found a [cloudflare-scrape](https://github.com/Anorov/cloudflare-scrape) Python module that uses external JS evaluation engine to calculate the number and send the request back to server. I'm not sure how to integrate it into [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org) though. Or maybe there's a smarter way without using JS execution? In the end, it's a form...

I'd apriciate any help.

Comment: what's wrong with executing the JS? a lot of content can't be reached without it...

Comment: @dandavis Scrapy doesn't do JS execution.

Comment: without JS, scraping is getting more useless all the time. you should consider using a browser to scrape. my scrape scripts can get behind logins, grab dynamic and paginated content, even fake-click to request more dynamic sub-content before scraping, and i don't think any have been more than 10 lines of code or needed a big external library. all you need is tampermonkey and a download routine... KISS. if you want it more automated, you can then switch the userscript to phantomJS or something like that.

Comment: for executing JS you could use [splash](https://github.com/scrapinghub/splash) which is totally integrated with scrapy.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

So I executed JavaScript using Python with help of [cloudflare-scrape](https://github.com/Anorov/cloudflare-scrape).

To your scraper, you need to add the following code:

```
def start_requests(self):
  for url in self.start_urls:
    token, agent = cfscrape.get_tokens(url, 'Your prefarable user agent, _optional_')
    yield Request(url=url, cookies=token, headers={'User-Agent': agent})
```

alongside parsing functions. And that's it!

Of course, you need to install cloudflare-scrape first and import it to your spider. You also need a JS execution engine installed. I had Node.JS already, no complaints.

Comment: Hi, I tried using your solution for a website using cloudflare - It seems like the right request is being sent, but I'm still timing out with 503 errors from the first request.

Here's what the reuqests look like: 

`DEBUG: "GET /cdn-cgi/l/chk_jschl?jschl_answer=386&jschl_vc=3ee197400dbcca30577bcb3949cf781f&pass=1446694346.755-esyN0f4s4%2F HTTP/1.1" 302 165
DEBUG: "GET /forumdisplay.php?29-DotA-Chat HTTP/1.1" 200 21367`


`2015-11-04 22:32:48 [scrapy] DEBUG: Gave up retrying <GET http://nadota.com/forumdisplay.php?29-DotA-Chat> (failed
3 times): 503 Service Unavailable`

Comment: @ddnm, I updated the code. It will work now. Change `cookies={"cfuid":token["cfuid"]}` to `cookies=token`

Comment: I get `Error parsing Cloudflare IUAM Javascript challenge` as per March 2019

Comment: cfscrape no longer works and no longer maintained, as per: https://github.com/Anorov/cloudflare-scrape/issues/347

Comment: this library is not working (28 april 2021). Probably developer not interested. `ValueError: Unable to identify Cloudflare IUAM Javascript on website. Cloudflare may have changed their technique, or there may be a bug in the script.`

Comment: (august 2021:) cfscrape and scrapy-cloudflare-middleware have not worked for a long time now. Any other hint ?

Answer (score 8):

Obviously the best way to do this would be to whitelist your IP in CloudFlare; if this isn't suitable let me recommend the [cloudflare-scrape](https://github.com/Anorov/cloudflare-scrape) library. You can use this to get the cookie token, then provide this cookie token in your [Scrapy request](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html) back to the server.

Answer (score -3):

If you're getting 503 Error you can follow these guidelines:

1. Go to `settings.py`
2. Search for: `USER_AGENT`
3. Here you will see the **default bot user agent** by scrapy.
   Replace that default with this:

   ```
   USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36'
   ```