# how to use cloudscraper together with scrapy

Tags: scrapy, scrapy-splash

I'm trying to parse data from a site,I use scrapy, but the site is protected by cloudflare. I found a solution, use [cloudscraper](https://github.com/VeNoMouS/cloudscraper), and this cloudscraper can really get around protection. But I don’t understand how it can be used with scrapy.

Trying to write something like this

```
import scrapy
   from scrapy.xlib.pydispatch import dispatcher
   import cloudscraper
   import requests
   from scrapy.http import Request, FormRequest
   class PycoderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
      name = 'armata_exper'
      start_urls = ['https://arma-models.ru/catalog/sbornye_modeli/?limit=48']
      def start_requests(self):
         url = "https://arma-models.ru/catalog/sbornye_modeli/?limit=48"
         scraper = cloudscraper.CloudScraper()
         cookie_value, user_agent = scraper.get_tokens(url)
         yield scrapy.Request(url, cookies=cookie_value, headers={'User-Agent': user_agent})

      def parse(self, response):
         ....
```

getting an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/utils/signal.py", line 30, in send_catch_log
    *arguments, **named)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pydispatch/robustapply.py", line 55, in robustApply
    return receiver(*arguments, **named)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/referer.py", line 343, in request_scheduled
    redirected_urls = request.meta.get('redirect_urls', [])
AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'meta'
Unhandled Error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/commands/crawl.py", line 58, in run
    self.crawler_process.start()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 309, in start
    reactor.run(installSignalHandlers=False)  # blocking call
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 1283, in run
    self.mainLoop()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 1292, in mainLoop
    self.runUntilCurrent()
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 913, in runUntilCurrent
    call.func(*call.args, **call.kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/utils/reactor.py", line 41, in __call__
    return self._func(*self._a, **self._kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/engine.py", line 135, in _next_request
    self.crawl(request, spider)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/engine.py", line 210, in crawl
    self.schedule(request, spider)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/engine.py", line 216, in schedule
    if not self.slot.scheduler.enqueue_request(request):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/scheduler.py", line 91, in enqueue_request
    if not request.dont_filter and self.df.request_seen(request):
builtins.AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'dont_filter'
```

please tell me how to do it right

Comment: An easy to implement alternative to cloudscrape could be [scrapy-cloudflare-middleware](https://github.com/clemfromspace/scrapy-cloudflare-middleware) which is build to work with Scrapy, although it seems to not receive any updates. You could also use [cloudflare-scrape](https://github.com/Anorov/cloudflare-scrape) which is the base of scrapy-cloudflare-middleware and seems to receive more frequent updates. See [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33290671/9003106) to see how to use it with Scrapy.

Comment: cloudflare added the changes and cloudflare-scrape is not working now, I wrote to the developer, but so far I have not received any answer. Therefore, I decided to use the module I asked about

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to integrate Scrapy and Cloudscraper by using [Scrapy downloader middlewares](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html).

This is the middleware that I came up with:

```py
import cloudscraper
import logging
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse

class CustomCloudflareMiddleware(object):

    cloudflare_scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper()

    def process_response(self, request, response, spider):
        request_url = request.url
        response_status = response.status
        if response_status not in (403, 503):
            return response
        
        spider.logger.info("Cloudflare detected. Using cloudscraper on URL: %s", request_url)
        cflare_response = self.cloudflare_scraper.get(request_url)
        cflare_res_transformed = HtmlResponse(url = request_url, body=cflare_response.text, encoding='utf-8')
        return cflare_res_transformed
```

I am using the `process_response` middleware method. If I detect that a response was 403 or 503 then I do the same request with `cloudscraper`. Otherwise I just continue the normal pipeline (one could also remove this `if` to always use cloudscraper for simplicity; or also define more refined conditions to use or not cloudscraper). Also, since `requests` responses are not the same as Scrapy, we need to transform them to a Scrapy response.

Finally, you must configure the middleware in the spider. I like to do this by defining the `custom_settings` class variable:

```py
class MyCrawler(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'mycrawlername'

    custom_settings = {
      'USER_AGENT': '...',
      'CLOSESPIDER_PAGECOUNT': 20,
      'DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES': {            
        'middlewares.CustomCloudflareMiddleware.CustomCloudflareMiddleware': 543,             
      }
    }

    # my rules...
    # my parsing functions...
```

(the exact path to the middleware will depend in your project structure)

You may find my complete example [here](https://github.com/lkuffo/web-scraping/tree/master/NIVEL%202/EJEMPLOS_ADICIONALES/cloudflarescrapy).

Comment: I implemented this and there are a few significant problems: 1) It's worrisome that you let the blocked request happen, and then immediately re-request with the cloudscraper (from the same IP). 2) You're not using anything from the request other than the URL. E.g., no cookies or other headers. 3) You're returning very little from the response (e.g., status code) 4) I ran into problems with the fact that cloudscraper will unzip responses but leave the header, leading to Scrapy trying to unzip the response. 5) Most importantly, using middleware breaks things like `DOWNLOAD_DELAY`.