# Can't scrape product title from a webpage

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape the title of the product avilable in this [webpage](https://www.cclonline.com/product/334427/GV-N3070AORUS-M-8GD-1-1/Graphics-Cards/Gigabyte-AORUS-GeForce-RTX-3070-MASTER-8GB-Overclocked-Graphics-Card-rev-1-1-/VGA5934/) using requests module, but the script always throws `AttributeError` even when the product title is in the page source (`ctrl + U`).

I've tried with (`throws AttributeError`):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'https://www.cclonline.com/product/334427/GV-N3070AORUS-M-8GD-1-1/Graphics-Cards/Gigabyte-AORUS-GeForce-RTX-3070-MASTER-8GB-Overclocked-Graphics-Card-rev-1-1-/VGA5934/'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.77 Safari/537.36',
}

res = requests.get(link, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
try:
    product_title = soup.select_one("h1 > span").get_text(strip=True)
except AttributeError: product_title = ""
print(product_title)
```

Expected output:

```
Gigabyte GeForce RTX 3070 Aorus Master 8GB OC GPU
```

> How can I scrape the product title from that webpage?

PS I've tried with this library [cloudscraper](https://pypi.org/project/cloudscraper/) as well, but no luck.

***EDIT:***

This is what I get `raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self) requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url` when I run the following piece of code:

```
import cfscrape

url = 'https://www.cclonline.com/product/334427/GV-N3070AORUS-M-8GD-1-1/Graphics-Cards/Gigabyte-AORUS-GeForce-RTX-3070-MASTER-8GB-Overclocked-Graphics-Card-rev-1-1-/VGA5934/'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.77 Safari/537.36',
}

token, agent = cfscrape.get_tokens(url, headers=headers)
print(token, agent)
```

I know I could have used the value of `cf_clearance` within cookies to access the page content, if I could get the value of token from above attempt.

Comment: Have you tried ```print(soup)``` to check if the source is similar to your browser and contains the info you look for?

Comment: When I print the `status_code`, this is `403` what I get.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33247662/how-to-bypass-cloudflare-bot-ddos-protection-in-scrapy/33252613

Comment: I think you just hit the cloudflare ddos wall

Comment: I went that route (your linked post) as well but could not get either token or agent. I only tried with the link I pasted above. However, I've been getting the same status_code from the beginning @FloLie.

Comment: You might not be able to bypass the cloudflare wall with pure `reqests`. Your best bet might be `selenium`.

Comment: I have tried with selenium, playwright e.t.c as well but no luck.

Comment: Some packages seem to have been created to bypass Cloudflare, maybe we should take a look at it? https://github.com/Anorov/cloudflare-scrape, https://github.com/VeNoMouS/cloudscraper

Comment: That is the library I first tried with @ce.teuf. Howwer, it failed miserably.

Comment: I am not surprised. I burped your url, and you need to solve obfuscated javascript challenge to bypass. It would take to many time (for me) to configure and bypass the wall. And note that the "challenges" imposed by Cloudflare change very regularly

Comment: Neither [cloudscrape](https://github.com/VeNoMouS/cloudscraper) or [cfscrape](https://github.com/Anorov/cloudflare-scrape) will be able to solve the Cloudflare javascript challenge, because these packages aren't being maintained publicly.  In the issue section of cfscrape the developer stated that there is now a paid subscription model, which is activity maintained.

Comment: @MITHU what is your discord account id?

Comment: Sorry @Life is complex, I don't have one really. Thanks.

Comment: @MITHU please create one and share it with me.

Comment: I'll do once I create one @Life is complex. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**This is only a placeholder for research that might be useful to others looking at this *Cloudflare bypass* issue.**

### Use Case

---

Scraping information from a website that is using either [Cloudflare CAPTCHA or Javascript challenge](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170136-Understanding-Cloudflare-Captchas-and-Challenge-Passage) for enhanced protection.

### Python Requests

---

Using a standard *Python Requests.Get* the *Cloudflare* service will return a 403 Forbidden error code.

```
import requests

URL = 'https://www.cclonline.com/product/334427/GV-N3070AORUS-M-8GD-1-1/Graphics-Cards/Gigabyte-AORUS-GeForce-RTX' \
      '-3070-MASTER-8GB-Overclocked-Graphics-Card-rev-1-1-/VGA5934/'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.77 Safari/537.36'}

response = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
print(f'Status Code: {response.status_code}')
print(f'Status Code Reason: {response.reason}')
# output
Status Code: 403
Status Code Reason: Forbidden
```

If we look at the *response.headers* we can see that a *Cloudflare* server is proxying our request to the target URL.

```
...continued from the code above
for key, value in response.headers.items():
    print(f'KEY NAME: {key}')
    print(f'KEY VALUE: {value}')
    print('-----------------------')
    # output 
    KEY NAME: Date
    KEY VALUE: Sun, 13 Jun 2021 16:39:03 GMT
    -----------------------
    KEY NAME: Content-Type
    KEY VALUE: text/html; charset=UTF-8
    -----------------------
    KEY NAME: Transfer-Encoding
    KEY VALUE: chunked
    -----------------------
    KEY NAME: Connection
    KEY VALUE: close
    -----------------------
    KEY NAME: Permissions-Policy
    KEY VALUE: accelerometer=(),autoplay=(),camera=(),clipboard-read=(),clipboard-write=(),fullscreen=(),geolocation=(),gyroscope=(),hid=(),interest-cohort=(),magnetometer=(),microphone=(),payment=(),publickey-credentials-get=(),screen-wake-lock=(),serial=(),sync-xhr=(),usb=()
    -----------------------
    KEY NAME: Cache-Control
    KEY VALUE: private, max-age=0, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
    -----------------------
    KEY NAME: Expires
    KEY VALUE: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT
    -----------------------
    KEY NAME: X-Frame-Options
    KEY VALUE: SAMEORIGIN
    -----------------------
    KEY NAME: cf-request-id
    KEY VALUE: 0aa7d6c7c4000007ff7201b000000001
    -----------------------
    KEY NAME: Expect-CT
    KEY VALUE: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
    -----------------------
    KEY NAME: Set-Cookie
    KEY VALUE: __cf_bm=72427e2af66c7177feeb88a847fae9c26b66c681-1623602343-1800-AZAmqDfaHZU8IXOH/i3BBVf8pGcws0Gc1Tln5yKUepe3utWlCpagxvALDW6wiHd2pli9Zl45Mg8gC/QSoUFhoes=; path=/; expires=Sun, 13-Jun-21 17:09:03 GMT; domain=.cclonline.com; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None
    -----------------------
    KEY NAME: Vary
    KEY VALUE: Accept-Encoding
    -----------------------
    KEY NAME: Server
    KEY VALUE: cloudflare
    -----------------------
    KEY NAME: CF-RAY
    KEY VALUE: 65ecc0b9383b07ff-ATL
    -----------------------
    KEY NAME: Content-Encoding
    KEY VALUE: gzip
    -----------------------
```

If we look at the *response.text* associated with the *Python Requests* we can see other evidence related to the *Cloudflare* protection.

```
...continued from the code above
print(response.text)
# output

truncated...

<title>Please Wait... | Cloudflare</title>
<meta name="captcha-bypass" id="captcha-bypass" />

truncated...

<form class="challenge-form managed-form" id="challenge-form" action="/product/334427/GV-N3070AORUS-M-8GD-1-1/Graphics-Cards/Gigabyte-AORUS-GeForce-RTX-3070-MASTER-8GB-Overclocked-Graphics-Card-rev-1-1-/VGA5934/?__cf_chl_managed_tk__=7d4597196bb14948881846ca16631b64c55f06d3-1623602854-0-AcX2yHJM2sCalL03Opq9RiFjASeYE0Xs0KG4XeG1lezzhzEyu-bL8xsdHuEjNIIKaJkWEmha4DhViRlqWEP_HREOdA8YAY7nnNkBAHbNMs6p_AWgYNLPnSNM13PO2I96hdABtoaaKjOzV4AyJQJ8f08XEW2flN97rPxIMeiR0tI1a3PiON2dN9E_YCyneAuCUfaYWUNGL0Bqd_rkYp3Ljb2zk_kGWizckr1fvhodSEjEB-ByYVK8ODNox2oZ4XPcmCYJ6UNDmbNc406BjMeTf3e72Z7vgdnt3V714VrGN4w_Y4VQ2X1V0OVKUKEH9B5Rxa_4fEZiMAAdxZ6idg69JYMKftuuLemr53n5WAwTwyX2G7N9jmjtarxEQcCqoj9oY7oSFwQTb3ZVb9i5EeavKaE1_67wxpyPybNidBDxhLazDEMefPZGDsV9mSziuIQ90nS5vn-7sUvC8BJATNWPbh6OduchXy-QcMeYhurtukUCm3oDQMP7r4g4qvDCWI3_-ku7u-B4G2XI2kwM_tLVEZiH5uHPjWpHE6eFWohiCTxd4p7vHg7z5ug9feRalYqu3GfInd82GZ-j-7nCqLDmPh2Sjlu6sJGfopqM3XlBrd1kgRZU3Z4uw6JIIqfH0M6K3_weTtem0-Z1zhDUBbVDvgJVeHNNh_bTxHGWbFB0f80tALBMbt67RftO5u1XBUZ-TRftteXBwJ8gmYzOZTo4lQOGQ_771urYXsTuW_sp8PwxvQpEyCnY8zD8dmVz0-waZhOet8MQMwduN2nfGUOrCMwUYO9McsBqzfsT5PJZVkDm-rYBBwqw0PIwvm1-N8ymAjrpSN6ps4FerqK1uQOo77FLiOq8JCOVqdETIZ9NO07A" method="POST" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">

truncated...

 <input type="hidden" name="r" value="d5db3eb87c9b42ec7f076916611c296abfd2c842-1623602854-0-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">
  <input type="hidden" name="cf_captcha_kind" value="h">
  <input type="hidden" name="vc" value="4845a44c225a1fa6a61708e11b613971">

truncated...

 <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    (function(){
        var isIE = /(MSIE|Trident\/|Edge\/)/i.test(window.navigator.userAgent);
        var trkjs = isIE ? new Image() : document.createElement('img');
        trkjs.setAttribute("src", "/cdn-cgi/images/trace/managed/js/transparent.gif?ray=65eccd326d61f331");
        trkjs.id = "trk_managed_js";
        trkjs.setAttribute("alt", "");
        document.body.appendChild(trkjs);
        var cpo=document.createElement('script');
        cpo.type='text/javascript';
        cpo.src="/cdn-cgi/challenge-platform/h/g/orchestrate/managed/v1?ray=65eccd326d61f331";
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(cpo);
    }());
    //]]>
    </script>
```

The information above shows that the Python Requests that was transmitted to the target URL was intercepted by a *Cloudflare* server, which is challenging the request.  This challenge has to be bypassed before the initial request will be allowed to continue.

### cfscrape Package

---

The OP stated that they attempted to use the [cfscrape](https://github.com/Anorov/cloudflare-scrape) Python Package to obtain token information from the *Cloudflare* server.

A standard cfscrape request provide identical responses as *Python Requests.*

```
import cfscrape

URL = 'https://www.cclonline.com/product/334427/GV-N3070AORUS-M-8GD-1-1/Graphics-Cards/Gigabyte-AORUS-GeForce-RTX' \
      '-3070-MASTER-8GB-Overclocked-Graphics-Card-rev-1-1-/VGA5934/'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.77 Safari/537.36'}

scraper = cfscrape.create_scraper(delay=10)
response = scraper.get(URL, headers=headers)
print(f'Status Code: {response.status_code}')
print(f'Status Code Reason: {response.reason}')
# output
Status Code: 403
Status Code Reason: Forbidden
```

The *cfscrape* package also supports the functions *get_tokens* and *get_cookie_string,* but both of these produce the 403 Forbidden error code.

From *cfscrape* source code:

```
def is_cloudflare_captcha_challenge(resp):
        return (
            resp.status_code == 403
            and resp.headers.get("Server", "").startswith("cloudflare")
            and b"/cdn-cgi/l/chk_captcha" in resp.content
        )


# the function above is called from this

def request(self, method, url, *args, **kwargs):
        resp = super(CloudflareScraper, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)

        # Check if Cloudflare captcha challenge is presented
        if self.is_cloudflare_captcha_challenge(resp):
            self.handle_captcha_challenge(resp, url)

        # Check if Cloudflare anti-bot "I'm Under Attack Mode" is enabled
        if self.is_cloudflare_iuam_challenge(resp):
            resp = self.solve_cf_challenge(resp, **kwargs)

        return resp
```

The *handle_captcha_challenge* function is what tries to solve the *Cloudflare* javascript challenge. [This section of the code](https://github.com/Anorov/cloudflare-scrape/blob/e510962c608382bcef5de75033d60cc98cb9561d/cfscrape/__init__.py#L140) is what is failing. It's unclear what part of that section is failing, so additional research and testing is required.

**PLEASE NOTE:** According to the package's developer [the module is no longer supported](https://github.com/Anorov/cloudflare-scrape/issues/406).

### cloudscraper Package

---

The OP also stated that they attempted to use the [cloudscraper](https://github.com/venomous/cloudscraper) Python Package to obtain token information from the *Cloudflare* server. It is worth nothing that *cloudscraper* was forked from *cfscrape,* so the syntax is similar.

*cloudscraper* gets the same 403 Forbidden error code as *cfscrape.*

```
import cloudscraper

URL = 'https://www.cclonline.com/product/334427/GV-N3070AORUS-M-8GD-1-1/Graphics-Cards/Gigabyte-AORUS-GeForce-RTX' \
      '-3070-MASTER-8GB-Overclocked-Graphics-Card-rev-1-1-/VGA5934/'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.77 Safari/537.36'}

scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper()
response = scraper.get(URL)
print(f'Status Code: {response.status_code}')
print(f'Status Code Reason: {response.reason}')
# output
Status Code: 403
Status Code Reason: Forbidden
```

The *cloudscraper* package also supports the functions *get_tokens* and *get_cookie_string,* but both of these produce the 403 Forbidden error code.

### selenium Package

---

The OP also stated that they attempted to use the [selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) Python package.

**SPECIAL NOTE:** During my testing I used selenium with webdrivers for *Google Chrome*, *Mozilla Firefox* and *Microsoft Edge*.

Within the last 12 months these Options could be used in *selenium* to bypass *Cloudflare* protection. Unfortunately, these Options do not work today

```
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
# additional disable-blink-features are available in Chromium source code on Github
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
```

Below is a *selenium* code example using the Chrome webdriver with the switches above.

```
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument(
    "user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.77 Safari/537.36")
chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/chromedriver', options=chrome_options)
URL = "https://www.cclonline.com/product/334427/GV-N3070AORUS-M-8GD-1-1/Graphics-Cards/Gigabyte-AORUS-GeForce-RTX-3070-MASTER-8GB-Overclocked-Graphics-Card-rev-1-1-/VGA5934"

driver.get(URL)
```

The code above opens a browser session, which is confronted with a *Cloudflare* Javascript challenge.  During testing with the switches mentioned above this challenge does not stop.  The *Cloudflare Ray ID,* which are unique id per request rotate many times before I manually terminated the session.

[image]

[seleniumwire](https://github.com/wkeeling/selenium-wire) is required to obtain the status code

Below is a *headless* mode Chrome webdriver session, which also shows the 403 Forbidden error code for the target URL.  The session also shows that [hcaptcha.com](https://www.hcaptcha.com/) anti-bot technology is now in the mix.

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument(
    "user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.77 Safari/537.36")
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/chromedriver', options=chrome_options)
URL = "https://www.cclonline.com/product/334427/GV-N3070AORUS-M-8GD-1-1/Graphics-Cards/Gigabyte-AORUS-GeForce-RTX-3070-MASTER-8GB-Overclocked-Graphics-Card-rev-1-1-/VGA5934"
driver.get(URL)

for request in driver.requests:
    print(f'Status Code: {request.response}')
    print(f'Host Name: {request.host}')
    # output 
    Status Code: 403 
    Host Name: www.cclonline.com
    -----------------------
    Status Code: 200 
    Host Name: www.cclonline.com
    -----------------------
    Status Code: 200 
    Host Name: www.cclonline.com
    -----------------------
    Status Code: 200 
    Host Name: www.cclonline.com
    -----------------------
    Status Code: 200 
    Host Name: www.cclonline.com
    -----------------------
    Status Code: 200 
    Host Name: www.cclonline.com
    -----------------------
    Status Code: 200 
    Host Name: www.cclonline.com
    -----------------------
    Status Code: 200 
    Host Name: www.cclonline.com
    -----------------------
    Status Code: 302 
    Host Name: hcaptcha.com
    -----------------------
    Status Code: 200 
    Host Name: newassets.hcaptcha.com
    -----------------------
driver.quit()
```

A standard Chrome webdriver session using the UI shows an iFrame with an *"I am human"* checkbox.

[image]

If I click the button manually or with *selenium* session, I'm prompted with a picture captcha, which increasing the complexity of bypassing the *Cloudflare* protection.

[image]

### cf_clearance cookie

---

When a *Cloudflare* CAPTCHA or Javascript challenge is solved a *cf_clearance* cookie is set in the client browser. The *cf_clearance* cookie has a default lifetime of 30 minutes, but is configurable by the *Cloudflare* client.

If you open the OP's target URL manually in a Google Chrome browser you can see the *cf_clearance* cookie using *Developer Tools*

It seem that the *cf_clearance* cookie lifetime is set for 60 minutes based on the UTC time this session started and the expiration date set for the cookie.

***So far I haven't found a way to extract this cookie using Python.***

[image]

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer? It does not solve the problem.