# How to get around Newspaper throwing 503 exceptions for certain webpages

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-newspaper, newspaper3k

I'm trying to scrape a number of webpages using `newspaper3k` and my program is throwing 503 Exceptions. Can anyone help me identify the reason for this and help me get around it? To be exact, I'm not looking to catch these exceptions but to understand why they are occurring and prevent them if possible.

```
from newspaper import Article

dates = list()
titles = list()

urls = ['https://www.rbnz.govt.nz/research-and-publications/speeches/2021/speech2021-06-29',
 'https://www.rbnz.govt.nz/research-and-publications/speeches/2021/speech2021-06-02',
 'https://www.rbnz.govt.nz/research-and-publications/speeches/2021/fec-mps-hearing-may-21',
 'https://www.rbnz.govt.nz/research-and-publications/speeches/2021/speech2021-05-06',
 'https://www.rbnz.govt.nz/research-and-publications/speeches/2021/fec-fsr-hearing-may-21',
 'https://www.rbnz.govt.nz/research-and-publications/speeches/2021/speech2021-03-04',
 'https://www.rbnz.govt.nz/research-and-publications/speeches/2021/fec-2019-20-reserve-bank-annual-review',
 'https://www.rbnz.govt.nz/research-and-publications/speeches/2020/speech2020-12-02',
 'https://www.rbnz.govt.nz/research-and-publications/speeches/2020/speech2020-10-28',
 'https://www.rbnz.govt.nz/research-and-publications/speeches/2020/speech2020-10-22',
 'https://www.rbnz.govt.nz/research-and-publications/speeches/2020/speech2020-10-19',
 'https://www.rbnz.govt.nz/research-and-publications/speeches/2020/speech2020-09-14']

for url in urls:
    speech = Article(url)
    speech.download()
    speech.parse()
    dates.append(speech.publish_date)
    titles.append(speech.title)
```

Here's my Traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ArticleException                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-217a6cafe26a> in <module>
     20     speech = Article(url)
     21     speech.download()
---> 22     speech.parse()
     23     dates.append(speech.publish_date)
     24     titles.append(speech.title)

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/newspaper/article.py in parse(self)
    189 
    190     def parse(self):
--> 191         self.throw_if_not_downloaded_verbose()
    192 
    193         self.doc = self.config.get_parser().fromstring(self.html)

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/newspaper/article.py in throw_if_not_downloaded_verbose(self)
    529             raise ArticleException('You must `download()` an article first!')
    530         elif self.download_state == ArticleDownloadState.FAILED_RESPONSE:
--> 531             raise ArticleException('Article `download()` failed with %s on URL %s' %
    532                   (self.download_exception_msg, self.url))
    533 

ArticleException: Article `download()` failed with 503 Server Error: Service Temporarily Unavailable 
for url: https://www.rbnz.govt.nz/research-and-publications/speeches/2021/speech2021-06-29 
on URL https://www.rbnz.govt.nz/research-and-publications/speeches/2021/speech2021-06-29
```

Comment: @Lifeiscomplex yes, but none of the examples worked to help me get around this specific problem, unfortunately.

Comment: Newspaper3k uses Python Requests.  The error is being thrown by that Python Package.   Run a test with the first URL with Python Requests and query the status code.  You will get 503.

Comment: Thanks, yes, you're right. `requests.get(url)` for any of the above urls will actually throw a 503 error. Any idea why? Could it be some throttling from the website?

Comment: I looked into this issue more.   You cannot scrape the site with with either Newspaper3k or Python Requests, BECAUSE the site is using `CloudFlare` and this is the answer to your issue.

Comment: I posted an answer on how to troubleshoot these errors in the future.  I hope that you find the answer useful in dealing with future issues like this one.

Comment: You're welcome.  I will update my usage document with this example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234697/discussion-between-christian-adib-and-life-is-complex).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can troubleshoot the `503 Server Error: Service Temporarily Unavailable` error with the Python Package Requests.

```
import requests

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'
}

base_url = 'https://www.rbnz.govt.nz/research-and-publications/speeches/2021/speech2021-06-29'
req = requests.get(base_url, headers=headers)
print(req.status_code)
# output 
503
```

*Why are we getting a 503 Server Error?*

Let's look at the content being returned by the server.

```
import requests

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'
}

base_url = 'https://www.rbnz.govt.nz/research-and-publications/speeches/2021/speech2021-06-29'
req = requests.get(base_url, headers=headers)
print(req.text)
# output

truncated...

<title>Website unavailable - Reserve Bank of New Zealand - Te Pūtea Matua</title>

truncated...

<p data-translate="process_is_automatic">This process is automatic. Your browser will redirect to your requested content shortly.</p>

truncated...

<form class="challenge-form" id="challenge-form" action="/research-and-publications/speeches/2021/speech2021-06-29?__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=73ad3f68fb15cc9284b25b7802626dd4ebe102cd-1625840173-0-ATQAZ5g7wCwLU2Q7agCqc1p59qs6ghpsYPVhDNwDN5r7vefk0P1UbjR4AJOUl0kUCZmDi-EVWX8XekL6VkqOgKTd1zqd5QWWlT3f2Dp_aUWQgCAH3bnS4x0wyc8-xGOLm-tcMKCXcTXH-OpiGoUX8u__bk1TIZ0gI_TYMB-oy0nJi7dMYLgJnvJhwhTllDoYUbCzmo2h2idIJPqIjNaAwupvbdpvHnrogPDnFhCe8Cco9-eKlq4w0G563f_OJ3M7YQChBjCoHYlT8baMoOLzP-Kb33rNmlG0uXhzoiIBROsPw9pavOrO1vsbqf31ZArDRuy0y7rsfrhAD7iU113zmypN81tgqgL_F8YTzygRvI_z3Cs2YOMxjB53-jq1pWwqsW_ItTaY7I3vh5lg_12EUzEddcwmuIj1wI2NbnA7EU06QNHYYn_Ye4TKM0gu9k4031hGybszE3nRKCdTXgMSgJbYhTJ6bJYPSb_2IHMUHlYyHksxePJ4C_5-5X8qIdJApSTFBfCLLLAZLrkFnBk7ep4" method="POST" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
 
truncated...

var a = document.getElementById('cf-content');

truncated...

<p>Your access to the Reserve Bank website has been restricted. If you think you should be able to access our website please email <a href="mailto:web@rbnz.govt.nz">web@rbnz.govt.nz</a>.
```

If we looked at the returned text we can see that the website is asking for your browser to complete a `challenge-form.`. If you look at the additional data points (e.g. `cf-content`) in the text you can see that the website is being protected by `CloudFlare.`

Bypassing this protection is extremely difficult.  Here is one of my recent answers on the complexity bypassing this protection.

[Can't scrape product title from a webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67887751/cant-scrape-product-title-from-a-webpage/67961181#67961181)