# Python cloudscraper requests slow, with 403 responses

Tags: python, web-scraping, cloudflare

I am using Cloduscraper Python library in order to obtain a JSON response from an url.
The probem is that I have to retry the same request 2-3 times before I get the correct output. The first responses have a 403 HTTP status code.

Here is my code:

```
import json
from time import sleep
import cloudscraper

url = "https://www.endpoint.com/api/"
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:95.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/95.0",
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}
json_response = 0
while json_response == 0:
    try:
        scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper()
        r = scraper.get(url, headers=headers)
        json_response = json.loads(r.text)
    except:
        print(r.status_code)
        sleep(2)
return json_response
```

What can I do in order to optimize my code and prevent the 403 responses?

Comment: [cloudscraper](https://github.com/VeNoMouS/cloudscraper) code base hasn't been updated in a while and I'm unsure if it is even supported at this time.

Comment: Here is something that I [wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67887751/cant-scrape-product-title-from-a-webpage/67961181#67961181) on bypassing a Cloudflare protected site.  This task takes effort and most Python packages become obsolete quickly, because the vendor mitigates these bypass techniques.

Comment: @Lifeiscomplex Thank you for all the information reported. Unfortunately cfscrape doesn't work in my case. Selenium is a lot slower than cloudscraper, maybe because I can't use the option 'headless' or I get a 403. Therefore, isn't there a supported library for bypassing cloudflare?

Comment: I looked at the Github account for cloudscraper.  I noted that they have a [development branch](https://github.com/VeNoMouS/cloudscraper/tree/dev) that was last updated 3 months again.  Clone this repo to your system to test it for the site that you want to scrape.

Comment: @Lifeiscomplex thank you for the suggestion; I tried the dev version of cloudscraper, but it performed as the master version

Answer (score 1):

You could use real browser to prevent some part of bot detection, here is the example with `playwright`:

```py
import json

from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

API_URL = 'https://www.soraredata.com/api/players/info/29301348132354218386476497174231278066977835432352170109275714645119105189666'

with sync_playwright() as p:
    # Webkit is fastest to start and hardest to detect
    browser = p.webkit.launch(headless=True)

    page = browser.new_page()
    page.goto(API_URL)

    # Use evaluate instead of `content` not to import bs4 or lxml
    html = page.evaluate('document.querySelector("pre").innerText')

try:
    data = json.loads(html)
except:
    # Still might fail sometimes
    data = None

print(data)
```

Comment: Is it also possible to perform a POST request with some data usign playwright?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, you could try using JavaScript's `fetch` inside `evaluate`

Comment: Also there is another way: open website with real `playwright` browser to bypass cloudflare, then copy all cookies and session stuff back to python and use them to do requests from python side without blocks

Comment: Moreover, playwright provides `expect_request` method, which can be used to capture existing POST request on some page, which is availalable with GET request

Comment: Thank you; considering some random data, could you provide a working example with a POST request using playwright?

Comment: or if you prefer, the following is something related to the same site of the question:
url: https://www.soraredata.com/api/offers/player
to_send = """
      {"player_id": "8244483723335967330548112608338433168438009441877418350246645421695467333117",        "scarcity":"Limited",        "start_date":"2021-12-21T11:27:04.946521Z",        "end_date":"2022-01-21T11:27:04.946521Z",        "currency":"Îž"}   
    """

Answer (score 0):

The `HTTP 403 Forbidden` response status code indicates that the server understands the request but refuses to authorize it.

If you had no authorization, I would suggest first of all, to check if the url you are sending the request to, needs any sort of permissions to authorize the request.

However you do get a response at the 2nd or 3rd trial, and what happens is that some servers will take a few seconds before returning the answer, so they require the browser to wait ~5 seconds before submitting the response.

I would suggest adding a delay, which can be passed as an argument to create_scraper():

`scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper(delay=10)`

If it is succesfull, then reduce the delay until it can no longert be reduced.

Comment: unfortunately delay=10 didn't improve the performance at all

Comment: can you please provide a bit more information about your endpoint, is it private or public? if private is there a VPN or any kind of IP whitelisting? if public, can you please share the actual url? When you say "didn't improve performance at all", do you mean it is still failing at first try? If so, can you please try a higher delay like 60s, just to see if you get a response at the first try?

Comment: the endpoint is public, in particular it's the  following "https://www.soraredata.com//api/players/info/29301348132354218386476497174231278066977835432352170109275714645119105189666".  I tried with delay 60, but I am still getting a lot of 403 response, also as the first ones